# Why aren't two dates equal in a query within Access?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables I'm trying to join on a date field. The date fields are like:

01/01/2009

01/01/2009 1:00:00 AM

01/01/2009 2:00:00 AM

.....

One table has multiple entries for each hour. The other is just a date conversion table. I built a conversion table to help line up data.

When I run the query I only get one entry. 
01/01/2009 1:00:00 AM

I should be getting a number of years of data returned.

I have tested the data in excel and it says other dates are equal. Also have both the fields within each table set to the same format. The format is Date/Time -> General Date

```
SELECT h2009v1.flow_rate_datetime, tblDateConv.DateTimeSE, h2009v1.flow_rate
FROM h2009v1 INNER JOIN tblDateConv ON h2009v1.flow_rate_datetime = tblDateConv.DateTimeSE;
```

Note: I tried changing the date formats to see if that made a difference.

Comment: You should post the SQL. Have a look at DATEVALUE.

Comment: Thank you :) You where right the datevalue function partly fixed things. You also need to use the timevalue function. It appears this is one case you can't use the query builder in access but must write your own SQL.

Comment: SELECT h2009v1.flow_rate_datetime, h2009v1.flow_rate, tblDateConv.DateTimeSE, tblDateConv.HESE, tblDateConv.DayAESO
FROM h2009v1 INNER JOIN tblDateConv ON (datevalue(h2009v1.flow_rate_datetime) = datevalue(tblDateConv.DateTimeSE) AND TIMEvalue(h2009v1.flow_rate_datetime) = TIMEvalue(tblDateConv.DateTimeSE));